# Who attempted to kill Tyrion Lannister?

Tags: game-of-thrones, book-adaptation

During the Battle of the Blackwater Tyrion is struck in the face with a sword in an attempt on his life. We know the actual attacker was Ser Mandon but being a knight of the Kingsguard it is understood that he must have been ordered to do so. Tyrion believes it was his sister who gave this order but it was, I believe, never proven or shown in the series who actually gave the order.
I was wondering, as I've never read the books, if they have any further details on who is truly behind the attack on Tyrion Lannister?

Comment: I don't think it is known, at least not to wikis.

Comment: There's dialogue in season 3 [quoted in this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/39280/9718) where both Cersei and Tyrion appear to conclude that Joffrey gave the order as an impulsive act of spite. The reasoning all makes sense, and if true, there wouldn't be any proof (there'd have just been a muttered order like *"make sure the imp doesn't survive"*, no elaborate plot, and surely even Joffrey wouldn't be stupid enough mutter it loud enough to be overheard)